# Characteristic polynomial of recurrence relation $\lambda^4 + \lambda^3 - 9\lambda^2 + 11\lambda -4 = 0$

Tags: polynomials

The characteristic polynomial of this recurrence relation is 
 $$λ^4  + λ^3 - 9λ^2 + 11λ- 4 = 0$$
or
$$(λ − 1)^3 \cdot (λ + 4) = 0.$$
So the solution is of the form $a_n = α({-4})^n + β~n^2 + γ~n + δ.$

How do you get to the $(-4)^n$ coefficient?

I thought the soultion is of the form

an = αn3 + βn2 + γn + δ.

Comment: Yes that is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the $(-4)^n$ from the factor $(\lambda +4)$.  You get one solution like this per factor, so if your equation were $(\lambda +4)(\lambda+2)(\lambda-3)=0$ you would have a solution $\alpha(-4)^n+\beta(-2)^n+\gamma(3)^n$.  The constant, $n$ and $n^2$ terms in your solution come from the factor $(\lambda-1)^3$